# How to hide all text, which are smaller than certain pixel and bring them back later using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dom

I'm working on a project, which in some cases requires to hide all small text (eg. less than 12px), and on some other event, bring them back. It's not a website, but something happening on the webkit browser. I don't have control over the content on the page (developed by the third party developers), but have control to modify it. I know I can loop through all tag elements and check font sizes and hide them if smaller than 12px, but it's not only inefficient, but the text can be changed to be shown again, say after an ajax call, which is "prohibited". Other solution would be to run that loop every couple seconds, but it's an expensive process.

Other task is to show small text on some other event, which is not too difficult to implement by just using simple custom class.

Comment: Because there are no class names for 12px, you will have to inspect the elements. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the code on page-load, and then when any AJAX call completes using jQuery's Global AJAX Event Handlers: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

```
$(function () {
    function findSmallText($root, state) {
        if (typeof $root == 'undefined') {
            $root = $(document);
        }
        if (typeof state == 'undefined') {
            state = 'none';
        }
        $.each($root.find('p, div, span, font, button, a'), function () {
            if ($(this).css('font-size').replace(/(px|pt|em)/gi, '') <= 12) {
                $(this).css('display', state);
            }
        });
    }

    //run the function when the DOM is ready
    findSmallText();

    //also run the function when any AJAX request returns successfully
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(findSmallText);
});
```

You can pass the `findSmallText` function two arguments:

1. `$root`: (jQuery object) the root element to start looking for small text, limit this as much as possible to increase performance (so unnecessary elements don't have to be scanned).
2. `state`: (string) the `display` property to add to the elements with small text, you can use `block` to show the elements.

Comment: +1, but your selector may not match all the elements the questioner wants to hide (notably missing is `p`, for instance). It will be quite hard to match everything without being horribly inefficient, though, so it will always be kind of a cop-out anyway.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use * to get all elements?

Comment: @shershams You could look for all elements, I used specific tags because if you can, it will be much faster to select by tag-name than to select everything.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good catch, thanks. Yeah I went with tag-names to try to be a bit more efficient. For instance if all text is contained within `<p>` tags then that should be the selection.

Comment: true. I was just thinking about custom tags developer could use... Do you think it worth including <body> to the selector? In case developer has something like <body> Bla bla <p>Yada yada</p> </body>. Also what happens if the developer uses em or pt instead of px?

Answer (score 0):

if the HTML structure doesnt change (no extra containers added thru AJAX) simply analyze the page onLoad (kinda like what Jasper suggests) but instead of re-running the analysis after each AJAX call you add a new class - let's call it `.HideMeInCertainCases` for the fun of it. That way you can hide / show everything you want with a simple selector whenever you want.
So instead of this line: `$(this).css('display', state);` use `$(this).addClass('HideMeInCertainCases');`

When the event you were talking about occurs you can then toggle the display state with this selector `$("HideMeInCertainCases").toggleClass("hideMe")`. Changing the display-attribute directly might break your layout as the nodes containing text might have different displays to begin with (block, inline, inline-block...). Of course `.hideMe { display:none; }` should be somewhere in your stylesheet. If you want the layout to stay the same and only hide the content use `visibility` instead of `display`